# Использование и обращение к std::pair в std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11

Допустим, есть map - вот такого вида:

```
map<string,pair<int,int>> operators_sw_map; //use in initialize method
```

есть метод, в котором происходит инициализация этого map:

```
void Initialize()
  { //второй параметр в pair - отвечает за приоритет операции
    //чем больше число - тем выше приоритет
    //0 - бинарная операция
   //1 - унарная операция
  //2  - блок скобок
operators_sw_map["&&"]=make_pair(0,0);
operators_sw_map["||"]=make_pair(1,0);
operators_sw_map["!"]=make_pair(2,1);
operators_sw_map["->"]=make_pair(3,0);
operators_sw_map["<-"]=make_pair(4,0);
operators_sw_map["<->"]=make_pair(5,0);
operators_sw_map["XOR"]=make_pair(6,0);
operators_sw_map["("]=make_pair(7,2);
operators_sw_map[")"]=make_pair(8,2);
 }
```

Далее, я использую этот map в switch:

```
map<string,pair<int,int>>::iterator it= operators_sw_map.find(oper_statement[i]);//ищем оператор


       if (oper_statement[i]=="!") {
           unar_operations=1;

       }

       else  {
           unar_operations=0;
       }
       // проходимся по сгенерированной таблице
       for (int j = 0; j < statement.size(); ++  j) {// столбец

           for (int d = 0; d < LogicalTable[j].size(); d++) { //строка

               switch (it->second) {
               case 0: //&&
               {
     // .....
```

**Вопрос:**
как вот здесь - `switch (it->second)`
обратиться к первому элементу `std::pair` - который, в свою очередь - является ключем в `map` ?

Comment: Ключ в map это `it->first`. Значение в map это `it->second` = (`it->second.first`, `it->second.second`). И используйте `unordered_map`, он быстрее.

Comment: вы ищете  oper_statement  в   operators_sw_map, это означает, что   он имеет тип  pair<string, pair<int, int>>. И как же вы вообше выполняете сравнение   if (oper_statement[i]=="!")?

Comment: до этого operators_sw_map имел вид map<string,int>, а oper_statement - это vector<string> - вот я и сравниваю string

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
auto& pair = operators_sw_map[i];
if(pair.first) {
    ....
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Что такое `operators_sw_map[i]`?